Laptop screen cuts out when hinge moved, only in Ubuntu 24.04, not Windows 11
The laptop is dual boot and it does not happen at all in Windows 11. Also when Ubuntu first boots it does not happen, only after a few hours. It's not heat related either as when it's happening in Linux I can reboot directly into Windows and it does not happen.
The laptop is a Huawei Matebook 14 2020 AMD (CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 4800H with Radeon Graphics GPU: AMD ATI Radeon RX Vega 6)
I've seen some similar posts about an issue with the graphics driver in 24.04 but not pointers to a bug or a workaround.
After 4 days of testing I can confirm that setting HandleLidSwitch=ignore does stop the screen flickering.
Unfortunately that means the laptop does not automatically sleep when I close the lid, but I can do that manually through the menu at the top right.

Can you post a screenshot of the problem? It is unclear to me what you mean by laptop screen cuts out when hinge moved

I think I might have solved this, edited /etc/systemd/logind.conf adding the following:
HandleLidSwitch=ignore
Still testing but so far (2 hours) the display has not cut out when moving the screen.

Please add that comment as an answer below so that it helps future users.

After 4 days of testing I can confirm that setting HandleLidSwitch=ignore does stop the screen flickering.
Unfortunately that means the laptop does not automatically sleep when I close the lid but I can do that manually through the menu at the top right.
